# SBT assembly jar exclusion

Tags: apache-spark, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly

Im using spark (in java API) and require a single jar that can be pushed to the cluster, however the jar itself should not include spark. The app that deploys the jobs of course should include spark.

I would like:

1. sbt run - everything should be compiled and excuted
2. sbt smallAssembly - create a jar without spark
3. sbt assembly - create an uber jar with everything (including spark) for ease of deployment.

I have 1. and 3. working. Any ideas on how I can 2. ? What code would I need to add to my build.sbt file?

The question is not relevant only to spark, but any other dependency that I may wish to exclude as well.

Comment: Suppose you use other libraries like Scalaz and Dispatch. Do you want that included or excluded from the smallAssembly?

Comment: good question. Preferably excluded -smallAssembly should only contain the code that is to be deployed on the cluster.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### % "provided" configuration

The first option to exclude a jar from the fat jar is to use `"provided"` configuration on the library dependency. `"provided"` comes from Maven's [provided](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) scope that's defined as follows:

> This is much like `compile`, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope `provided` because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Since you're deploying your code to a container (in this case Spark), contrary to your comment you'd probably need Scala standard library, and other library jars (e.g. Dispatch if you used it). This won't affect `run` or `test`.

### packageBin

If you just want your source code, and no Scala standard library or other library dependencies, that would be `packageBin` built into sbt. This packaged jar can be combined with dependency-only jar you can make using sbt-assembly's `assemblyPackageDependency`.

### excludedJars in assembly

The final option is to use `excludedJars in assembly`:

```
excludedJars in assembly := {
  val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
  cp filter {_.data.getName == "spark-core_2.9.3-0.8.0-incubating.jar"}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For beginners like me, simply add the `% Provided` to Spark dependencies to exclude them from an uber-jar:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.0" % Provided
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.4.0" % Provided
```

in `build.sbt`.

Comment: If you do that though, you won't be able to run your project directly from an IDE or sbt anymore for development `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$`.

Comment: AFAIK, in Intellij, there is an option to configure to download jars with provided scope as well. Other IDEs must also have such options.